# How can I install php5-mcrypt

Tags: apt, apache2, php, lamp

When I try to use `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` to install php5-mcrypt, I receive the following error. I used `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` to install the php5

```
ahmad@ubuntu:/var/www/html$ sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-mcrypt is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-mcrypt' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @edwinksl 16.04

Answer (score 7):

php5-mcrypt (MCrypt module for php5) has been updated to php7.0-mcrypt (libmcrypt module for PHP) in Ubuntu 16.04, 16.10 and 17.04. The command `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` in Ubuntu 16.04 searches the package list files for all *Task:* fields and gets all with *lamp-server*, among them is php7.0. Then it installs those packages the standard way with `sudo apt-get install package1 package2...`

In Ubuntu 16.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt
```

In Ubuntu 17.10 and 18.04 php5-mcrypt has been updated to php7.1-mcrypt.

Comment: This does not answer the question since we don't need mcrypt for PHP 7 but for PHP 5.

Comment: The latest version that has php5-mcrypt in its default repositories is Ubuntu 14.04. php5-mcrypt can be downloaded manually from https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/php5-mcrypt.